# Transaction cannot have multiple recordsets with this cursor type error Update Filemaker Linked Server from SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, filemaker

I am trying to use SQL Server 2012 running on Windows Server 2012 R2 to update a linked Filemaker 13 server. My select queries and updates/inserts into my SQL Server tables from Filemaker work. However, when I try and update Filemaker from SQL Server I get the following error:

```
OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "CET_REGISTRATIONS" returned message "Unspecified error".
OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "CET_REGISTRATIONS" returned message 
"Transaction cannot have multiple recordsets with this cursor type. Change the cursor type, commit the transaction, or close one of the recordsets.".
Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "CET_REGISTRATIONS".
```

I am using the following query to perform the update:

```
update OPENQUERY(CET_REGISTRATIONS, 
                    'select "Current",
                            "Term ID",
                            "_kp_ClassByStudentID",
                            "_kr_StudentID",
                            "DE_r_task1",
                            "DE_r_task2",
                            "DE_w_task1",
                            "DE_w_task2",
                            "DE_w_task3",
                            "DE_w_task4",
                            "DE_w_task5",
                            "DE_l_task1",
                            "DE_l_task2",
                            "DE_s_task1",
                            "DE_s_task2",
                            "DE_s_task3",
                            "DE_r_final",
                            "DE_w_final",
                            "DE_l_final",
                            "DE_s_final",
                            "DE_o_final_total"
                    from "Class by Student"')
                set [DE_r_task1] = CAST(read_test1_Scaled as float),
                    [DE_r_task2] = cast(read_test2_scaled as float),
                    [DE_w_task1] = cast(writ_literatureReview as float),
                    [DE_w_task2] = cast(writ_exposition as float),
                    [DE_w_task3] = cast(writ_groupReport as float),
                    [DE_w_task4] = cast(writ_synthSummary as float),
                    [DE_w_task5] = cast(writ_critEvaluation as float),
                    [DE_l_task1] = cast(list_test1_scaled as float),
                    [DE_l_task2] = cast(list_test2_scaled as float),
                    [DE_s_task1] = cast(speak_groupPres as float),
                    [DE_s_task2] = cast(speak_indivPres as float),
                    [DE_s_task3] = cast(speak_tutorialDiscus as float),
                    [DE_r_final] = cast(read_total as float),
                    [DE_w_final] = cast(writ_total as float),
                    [DE_l_final] = cast(list_total as float),
                    [DE_s_final] = cast(speak_total as float),
                    [DE_o_final_total] = cast(overall_total as float)
                from  OPENQUERY(CET_REGISTRATIONS, 
                                'select "Current",
                                        "Term ID",
                                        "_kp_ClassByStudentID",
                                        "_kr_StudentID",
                                        "DE_r_task1",
                                        "DE_r_task2",
                                        "DE_w_task1",
                                        "DE_w_task2",
                                        "DE_w_task3",
                                        "DE_w_task4",
                                        "DE_w_task5",
                                        "DE_l_task1",
                                        "DE_l_task2",
                                        "DE_s_task1",
                                        "DE_s_task2",
                                        "DE_s_task3",
                                        "DE_r_final",
                                        "DE_w_final",
                                        "DE_l_final",
                                        "DE_s_final",
                                        "DE_o_final_total"
                                from "Class by Student"') filemaker
                inner join dbo.termData
                on filemaker.[_kp_ClassByStudentID] = termData.StbyCurrentClassID
                inner join dbo.DEC10assessmentDataNumeric local_table
                on local_table.studentID = termData.studentID
                where local_table.[studentID] = 34114 and local_table.[assessmentLookup] = 3 and 
                        termData.[termID] = '316a'
```

I am casting to `float` since supposedly the `number` [field in Filemaker](http://help.filemaker.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/6476) is equivalent to ODBC `SQL_DOUBLE` which is [equivalent to SQL Server's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729(v=vs.110).aspx)  `float` and I am pulling from `decimal` fields in SQL Server.

I have `RPC`, `RPC Out` and `Use Remote Collation` all enabled for the linked server, which I believe are all required for performing updates.

[image: Linked server settings]

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already done, have a look at the FieMaker ODBC guide:

[FileMaker® 15 ODBC and JDBC Guide](https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/docs/15/en/fm15_odbc_jdbc_guide.pdf)

I suspect, that the queries on ODBC driver have to comply to the internal FIleMaker SQL syntax, which is different and more limited in comparison to  T-SQL.

Try to simplify query, get result and then add extras gradually.